# Can I install a rocket stove inside my house?

Tags: building-regulations, woodstove

After having build a this type of [rocket stove](http://prepared-housewives.com/how-to-build-a-rocket-stove-and-impress-the-boys/)<sup>(*)</sup>, I was wondering if you are allowed to build a [rocket stove mass heater](http://www.richsoil.com/rocket-stove-mass-heater.jsp) into your house?

Are there any restriction?

<sup>(*)</sup> I don't think it's a rocket stove. That would need to re-burn the fumes.

<sup>I'm not affiliated to both websites whatsoever.</sup>

Comment: What country? The mass heater system linked to, if properly built with attention to detail (proper firebox, draft and sealing of combustion/smoke area from living space) is similar to how Finnish and Russian ceramic heating systems work. You build a hot, completely combusting fire and warm a thermal storage system.

Comment: @fiascolabs holland, wanted it to keep it general...

Comment: And, In Many LAHJs, the Russian/Finnish Masonry heater will be easily approved - since it's built with more traditional masonry materials and chimney; and has a long track record. LAHJs tend towards a good deal more skepticism towards cob as fire-containment and horizontal venting... As for making the question general, the answers to such questions are never general - they can literally vary hugely across a town line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will be up to the LAHJ - or **Local Authority Having Jursidiction**. Figure out who that is (if you need building permits, it's usually whoever issues and/or does inspections related to them) and ask.

Don't be overly shocked if the answer is no - I suspect most RMHs in dwellings are located in places with no or very minimal inspections/code enforcement, as the building code folks tend to be a bit conservative about fire and houses - not having people killed in house fires is a big part of why they exist. As such they can be very slow to accept non-traditional approaches to containing fires in houses. On the other hand, they may be able to suggest an approach that keeps them happy.

Comment: In the US, you would have to be in a rural area where stove inspections or code restrictions are not enforced. Too many house fires and carbon monoxide deaths... Whole family except the 9 year old son died from the latter about 2 years ago in our county.